# Can't create shortcut or desktop from JNLP

Tags: java, java-web-start, shortcut-file, desktop-integration

I got most part of Web Start JNLP to work except the desktop creation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080">
    <information>
      <title>Demo</title>
      <vendor>Saintonics</vendor>
      <homepage href="http://www.bizfans.net"/>
      <description>Web Start Version</description>
      <description kind="short">Web Start Version</description>
      <offline-allowed/>
      <icon href="images/bizfans.png"/>
      <icon kind="splash" href="images/bizfans.jpg"/>
      <shortcut online="false">
        <desktop/>
        <menu submenu="BizFans App"/>
      </shortcut>
    </information>
    <information os="Windows">
      <icon href="images/bizApp.png" kind="shortcut"/>
    </information>
    <security>
      <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
      <j2se version="1.6+"/>
      <jar href="LoneStar.jar" main="true" download="progress"/>
    </resources>
    <update check="always"/>
    <application-desc main-class="chatclient.app.LoneStar">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The recent Java doc indicate "desktop" element should have same parent as "shortcut", but most online example place the "desktop" under "shortcut"... either way I couldn't create the desktop icon on my app, anyone would be kind enough to shed some light?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: What is it, is it some kind Parser? And shame that we are blocked on few US major portals from this part of world, don't ask why ..... Andrew can you at least tell me is "desktop" element sitting in right place, becoz according the recent doc "desktop" shouldn't be under "shortcut"

Comment: *"Andrew can you at least tell me.."*  That's what I designed and wrote JaNeLA for.  After encoding the XSD and including it in the app., I no longer even have to know the correct form, since I *have a tool that **tells** me.*  .. *"What is it, is it some kind Parser?"*  It parses a JNLP according to an XSD, then does other checks that are either too complex for XSD or completely outside its bounds (e.g. availability of resources).

Comment: *"And shame that we are blocked on few US major portals from this part of world, don't ask why ....."*  Yes it is a shame and no I won't ask.  The latter because this is really your problem to fix, and if you cannot organize a computer with an IP capable of downloading from my Google share drive (which as far as I understand, is available to most places around the world), it is really no skin off my nose.

Comment: Oh sure I can manage to get around it. I was just tring to understand the nature of your tool. Thnx mate!

Comment: Hi Andrew, the program generated following error:

Comment: *"..following error:"*  Please don't post code snippets or error output in code comments where it is mostly illegible.  Instead  [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31606744/edit)..

Comment: Oh, and note that the tool offers a text report.